# "Help us Grow This Site" Twitter/X and Facebook buttons on Public Beta sites broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, beta-sites, sharing

If you go to any public beta site's homepage, [Programming Language Design and Implementation](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/) for example, you'll find a box like this:

[image]

The Facebook and Twitter/X share buttons rely on a service called [AddThis](https://www.addthis.com/) which was shut down at the end of May 2023. This means that the share buttons (except for email) are unusable. They should probably be updated to use the same share method used by the "share" link on questions/answers.

Comment: Well, SE had like 7-8 years. It was clear as crystal it's the end of that service when Oracle bought them. Pity.

Comment: Just remove those options, everyone knows how to take a url and share it wherever they want.

Comment: Looks like this box has been removed entirely now, as @KevinB suggested.